# how to write to a file stream asynchronously using async/await from multiple threads in a thread-safe manner

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have an extremely simple logging utility that is currently synchronous. It gets called from UI (WPF) and threadpool threads (Task.Run) and uses `lock(_stream){_stream.WriteLine(message);}` for thread safety. I'd like to add an asynchronous write method but not sure how to make it threadsafe.

1. Will the following async method work?
2. Will it play nice with the existing synchronous method and can they be used together without issues?
3. Assuming the previous is resolved, should the final `Debug.WriteLine` go inside the `try` block or after the `finally` where it currently is - does it make a difference?

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _sync = new SemaphoreSlim(1);    

public static async Task WriteLineAsync(string message)
{
    if (_stream != null)
    {
        await _sync.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            await _stream.WriteLineAsync(string.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + message));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            _sync.Release();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), message);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `BlockingCollection<T>` that has much of the functionality built-in to be used out of the box.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a semaphore for mutual exclusion. There are significant differences between a semaphore with a count of 1 and a mutual exclusion primitive such as `lock`. Use a `lock` here rather than a semaphore. If you think it's appropriate, use [SpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.SpinLock.aspx).

Comment: @JimMischel I don't understand. You can't use `await` inside of `lock`. So how would you `lock` asynchronously?

Comment: You're right. I thought there was a `TryEnterAsync` on `Monitor` or `SpinLock`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the following async method work?

If the stream is set up properly, then yes, i see no reason why it wouldn't

> Will it play nice with the existing synchronous method and can they be used together without issues?

If your synchronous methods use the same `SemaphoreSlim` and use the synchronous `Wait`, they should play along nicely.

> Assuming the previous is resolved, should the final Debug.WriteLine go inside the try block or after the finally where it currently is - does it make a difference?

If the debug message should be written if and only if the stream successfully writes a message to the stream, it should be inside your `try` block, after the call to `WriteLineAsync`.

Comment: And if the debug message should be written, whether or not the stream writing succeeds, and in the same order as the messages written to the stream (if any), then it should go in the `try` block, before the call to `WriteLineAsync`. (I am assuming here that `Debug.WriteLine` does not fail.)

Comment: It appears that `SemaphoreSlim` does not have a `WaitOne()` method. Maybe `Wait()` would be the equivalent?